# How to stop sound in the middle of playing

Tags: actionscript-3, media, audio

I'm trying to write a bit of code that plays a sound while a buttons pressed however if the button has been pressed and the sound is playing then the sound is paused and played again rather then just playing and overlapping.

this is what I have

```
    var sound:alarm = new alarm();
    var isPlaying:Boolean = false;

    public function Main()
    {
        button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,playSound);
    }
    
    public function playSound(e:Event):void
    {
        if(isPlaying)sound.stop();
        sound.play();
        isPlaying=true;
    }
```

at first glance It seemed to have worked but then I saw the following in my output

> TypeError: Error #1006: stop is not a function.
> at Main/playSound()
>
> TypeError: Error #1006: stop is not a function.
> at Main/playSound()

so apparently it works although stop is not a method of the Sound class. what would be the proper way of implementing this? Also I've been wondering if there is a more proper condition I can use, because with this code sound.stop() is called every time the function is entered after the first button click, is there a method that allows me to check in real time whether or not a sound is playing?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the function `playSound(e:Event)` should be `playSound(e:MouseEvent);`
Also your right `stop()` is not a method of the `Sound` class, however your not using the `Sound` class, your using the `alarm` class (unless the alarm class extends the Sound class).
On another note, I searched google and this popped up, [Flash Play/Pause Sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690178/flash-play-pause-sound-toggle-button)

#### Update:

```
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
// Make sure to import the SoundChannel class

var sc:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var sound:Sound = new alarm();
var isPlaying:Boolean = false;
var pausePos:Number = 0;

public function Main()
{
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,playSound);
}

public function playSound(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(isPlaying) {
        pausePos = sc.position;
        sc.stop();
        isPlaying = false;
    } else {
        sc = sound.play(pausePos);
        isPlaying = true;
    }
}
```

This code should work, however I have not tested it so if any errors are given or the desired result is not met just let me know and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Good catch...I just noticed that myself.

Comment: In the properties for the sound clip in my library under class name the base class is "flash.media.Sound" is that the same as extending the sound class, or will I have to make an entirely new as3 file

Comment: That is the same as extending the sound class, change your code to this though, `var sound:Sound = new alarm();`. Also add a `SoundChannel` variable for instance: `var sc:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();`. I'll update my answer with some code

Comment: changing the type for my sound variable cause the following compiler error "Main.as, Line 19 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method stop through a reference with static type flash.media:Sound.
", so something must be working, at least its recognizing the error in compile-time

Comment: It's throwing that error because the `Sound` class does not have a `stop` method. Check the updated code above, the `SoundChannel` class used in conjunction with the `Sound` class will give you the desired result.

Comment: Thanks! this seems to work, I'm watching a video tut right now on how to properly use the soundchannel. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer...okay, entire answer from me :). Instead of using the sound object, try the SoundChannel object. It offers more options, including volume and balance control, and most prominently, stop.

Documentation should provide enough info for using it. It's relatively common.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundChannel.html